# Why useEffect dont hit infinite loop in this case?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.I learnet that use effect is invoked when the compo is first initialised and when there are changes in props or state.But why in this case when i am changing some state from false to true there is not a infinite loop,but when i do that on array then there is an infinite loop from useEffect.

I am asking why it hits infintie loop when i make changes in state in array,but not with booloean value ?
What is the difference ?

```
//runs twise once for the first initalising once when i update the state

function App() {
  const [bool,setBool] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setBool(true);
    console.log("in use effect");
  })

  return (
    <div>

     </div>
  );
}

export default App;


//hits infinite loop 
function App() {
  const [array,setArray] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setArray([1,2,3]);
    console.log("in use effect");
  })

  return (
    <div>

     </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with a simple example:

```
function App() {
    const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);

    return (<div>{bool}</div>);
}
```

The App is rendered for the first time, and we see a div with `false` in it. Nothing needs to happen anymore, as we don't have an effect inside our component(s).

Now a bit more complex situation. Lets try to update the state:

```
function App() {
    const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setBool(true);
    });

    return (<div>{bool}</div>);
}
```

First we render the `App` with the default state, which is `false`. The effect gets executed and updates the state to `true`. Note that the effect runs after `false` has been rendered to the screen. Now in order to update this value on screen, it needs to decide if it needs to rerender `App`. It checks what it had before `false` and it compares it with what it has gotten now: `true`. It notices that these values aren't the same (`false !== true` yields `true`), so it rerenders App. While it does this, the effect is called once more. It updates the state to `true` (again), and the App checks if it needs to rerender again. Now it sees nothing has changed (`true !== true` yields `false`), so App isn't rerendered for this run.

Arrays have different equality. Two new empty arrays aren't equal to each other (`[] === []` yields `false`), as well as what is inside the arrays isn't compared (`[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` yields `false`). If we had to compare if we needed to rerender the component, we'd get a definite 'yes' on each call, leading to an infinite loop, or a stackoverflow depending on the implementation.

A related issue can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17688

Comment: A perfect answer.Thank you